# How to simplify the heat equation $u_{t}-\Delta u=\sin(u)$by substitution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Given $u_{t}-\vartriangle u=\sin(u)$ for $x \in \Omega$ and $t>0$, how would one substitute $u$ with a function $v$ such that this equation reduces to the form $v_{t}-\vartriangle v=0$?

Comment: Why do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this is possible. The reason is that for suitable $\Omega$ (e.g. large intervals) the stationary equation $-\Delta u = \sin x$ has more than solution under zero Dirichlet boundary conditions while the equation $-\Delta v = 0$ has only one solution.

More loosely arguing, if this were possible, there should also be a similar transformation that turns solutions of the scalar ode $u' + \lambda u = \sin u$ into solutions of $v' + \lambda v = 0$, for arbitrary positive $\lambda$. But the zero solution of the first equation is unstable for $\lambda < 1$ while it is always stable for the second one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. I was doing a problem like $u_{t}-\vartriangle u + cu =f$ and when I substitute $u$ with a $v=e^{ct}u$ the original equation reduces nicely. So I was wondering whether in this case we can also do the same thing, say, at least make some $v_{t}-\vartriangle v = something not about u$.